# Hibernate - join tables without NamedNativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

While joining multiple tables on my project using Hibernate jpa /Spring (annotation driven), I had to use the NamedNativeQuery annotation to achieve my objective to extract a distributed resultset spanning multiple tables. This may be a question that merely serves academic merit, but given that I am starting out on Hibernate - is there another way to achieve table joins without having to fall back on queries native to the database dialect?

Comment: show your native query and your entities. Maybe we can see something whats helping you.

Comment: You can chain createAlias method calls on Criteria instance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I believe this is exactly what you need: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-tuple

Criteria Queries is a way of building a complete query just using  its API. If I were you, I'd give it a try.

By the way, according to your question, the reason for using native queries is just for retrieving a specific set of columns. If this is the case, you can also write it using HQL as well. The query doesn't necessarily needs to be native.